# Training a CNN model by initialising its weights and bias

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to train a model by initializing its weights from a saved model,following is the code i am using -

```
        la = saved_model.get_layer(name='conv2d')
        out = la.get_weights()
        kernel,bias = out[0],out[1]
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input=val_in, filters=kernel, padding='SAME', strides=(1, 1, 1, 1))
        relu = tf.nn.relu(conv+bias)
```

using this method i won't be able to update the bias terms, how to initialize the weights and bias such that they get updated will training.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to use a `keras.layers.Conv2D` layer so you can easily build a model and train it rather than using the lower level tensorflow routines.  You can set the weights of an individual layer in a keras model using `set_weights` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#set_weights.

Comment: Is there no way to do it using tf.nn.con2d ?

Comment: I mean if you don't want to use the keras layers you could create a manual training loop.  You could then just compute graidents on that weights variable and then pass those grqidents to the optimizer.  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch